# How to pass function input as string R?

Tags: r, string, function

For example, if I was reading in multiple files from excel in which some were to be read without skipping first row and some weren't, and I wanted to code this in how would I do it?

`additional_read_param <- "skip = 1"`

`read_excel("mtcars.xlsx", sheet = 1, additional_read_param )`

How do I actually get this to work?

Comment: You can use `eval(parse`

Comment: Ahh, I see - so you construct your function call as a string and pass it into `eval(parse( string here ) ) `. Is this the *only* way to do it?  Is there a way to have the function be able to process parameters passed as string?  I got it working using the eval-parse method

Comment: Another option is to have a named `list` and pass the parameters to the function in `do.call`

Comment: How would I pass the string `skip = 1` or variation of it into a list for do.call?  `do.call(read_excel, list(file = file_path, sheet = 1)` works but variations of trying to add `additional_read_param` to it doesn't work

Comment: Let's say I have 10 files.  8 of them I do not want read with `skip = 1`, 2 of them I do.  I could do an if/else and call 2 different `read_excel` but I'm interested in a way that doesn't requiring double the code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will work but you can try
read_excel("mtcars.xlsx", sheet = 1, paste(additional_read_param))

Comment: Did you test this before you posted it as an answer?

Comment: If you're making a suggestion ("not sure if this will work") rather than a full answer, that's better done in comments once you have the rep for it

Comment: It work for me but I'm no sure if it the same for random_passerby123